# How to Initialize ViewController from LaunchScreen.Storyboard

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, storyboard

When I try to instantiate ViewController from *Main.Storyboard* in another ViewController I doing something like this:

```
SplashViewController splashVC = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("Splash") as SplashViewController;
```

Where Storyboard is "the UIStoryboard from which this UIViewController was created".

However, I need to Instantiate ViewController *from LaunchScreen.Storyboard* at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write code in `LaunchScreen.Storyboard` if you need to start your application immediately you can write your code `FinishedLaunching` as it is first method to be called soon after Launching. Write your code here.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you **can't** Instantiate ViewController from LaunchScreen.Storyboard.

The launch screen is what first appears when the user taps the app icon before the app is finished launching. It shows a single, static screen. It can't be dynamic and it can't use any custom classes or code.

And

> You cannot specify a custom class name in the storyboard and expect
>   the system to give you the option to execute code at this stage by
>   calling viewDidLoad. Remember, the app hasn’t launched yet.

Refer: [replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/#targetText=You%20can%20specify%20a%20storyboard,as%20your%20Launch%20Screen%20File.)